# Encrypted Passwords on Exim Mailserver (Vestacp)

Tags: ssl, password, exim

I just setup an Ubuntu 14.04 Server with VestaCp and want to secure the Mailserver. I already enabled ssl for exim and dovecot.
The only thing I'm still fighting with is exim to accept encrypted passwords.

Dovecot works with them already, but I cannot find information on how to enable them in exim. If I'm not mistaken VestaCp uses Exims authenticate over dovecot support.

I followed this thread and did the dovecot changes (which worked) - thank you google translate:
https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=3811&p=6036&hilit=md5#p6036

But the exim configuration doesn't work and I always get the error:

```
Exim configuration error in line 164 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp:
  option "dovecot_md5" unknown
Invalid new configfile /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp, not installing 
/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp to /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

Where do I need to define this dovecot authenticate option for md5 or another encryption?

How can I enable encrypted passwords in exim?
Or is it not necessary to encrypt passwords, when authenticating over SSL?

Answer (score 1):

you appear to be using a Debian system because it uses template files in /etc/exim4/ to generate the /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated file, which is what Debian's exim4 is configured to read.  You can learn a lot about how Debian manages the exim installation by reading their provided file /usr/share/doc/exim4-base/README.Debian.gz.  I will hereafter refer to "exim" when describing standard exim configuration and settings, and exim4 when describing Debian specifics.

The error message tells me that you put that config snippet near the beginning of the exim configuration.  That's the global configuration section, so it's interpreted as a global variable, and there is no such variable as "dovecot_md5" which causes the error.  As far as I can tell, you are attempting to do the right thing, you erred only in *WHERE* you placed this in the configuration file.  I can't read that language, but item #2 in the URL you referenced is basically saying:

```
In /etc/exim/exim.conf (after "begin authenticators")
```

The above directions assume a standard Exim installation.  However, since you have a Debian exim4 system, you instead need to edit the **/etc/exim4/conf.d/auth/30_exim4-config_examples**, which is used to assemble the template file /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template (which is then used to generate the /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated).  In that file, go down to near the end of the file.  After the phrase "begin authenticators", add the section referenced in your URL and restart Exim4.  Restarting will reconfigure the exim4.conf.template file, and then rebuild the config.autogenerated file.

Test and make sure it works as expected.

Comment: The above assumes you are using the default "split config" system.  If your system is not using the Debian exim4 split config, then you would edit the exim4.conf.template file instead of the 30_exim4-config_examples file.  Only you can know which your system is configured to use.